# Unable to insert form data to the sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have simple form which reads `users name`,`email`,and `city`. I have created a database and a table with fields `id`,`name`,`email` and `city`. When I run the code I don't encounter any errors or exceptions,but unable to see the inserted data into table. Following is my code

```
SqlConnection con = 
    new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = 
    new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_insert  values ( " + Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text) + "," + "'" + txtName.Text + "'" + "," + "'" + txtEmail.Text + "'" + "," + "'" + txtboxCity.Text + "'" + ")", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I have attached my database screenshots.
    Database design:

[image]

This is output I get after running my code.
Output with null value stored:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error when executing this query?

Comment: I'm not too sure on the problem you are having, but just wanted to give you a heads up on SqlParameter's https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx The code you have written is highly susceptible to SQL injection, so I would definitely recommend adding SqlParameter's if this project is to be more than just practice / fun

Comment: @un-lucky iam not getting errors while running this program

Comment: are you sending ID as well ??? :O:O

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt yeah i am sending ID as well

Comment: @SameerBetageri what error come when you try to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into tbl_insert values(@name,@email,@add)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtadd.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

i suspect the column `id` is in Auto Number

if not just add another parameter to the query and `cmd.Parameters`

Comment: If the column `id` is Identity, he should gives error but he already mentioned: *i don't encounter any errors or exceptions*.

Comment: same problem continued...no error debugging showed data is added correctly but it is not appearing in table

Answer (score 3):

You should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and get rids from quote problems:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_insert  values (@id,@name,@Email,@City)");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtboxCity.Text);
```

Although specify the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtName.Text;
```

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)